# Can I bypass iTunes Parental Restrictions on iOS devices?

Tags: itunes, ios, appletv, parental-controls

I currently have all my DVDs ripped and stored on a Windows Media Centre box.  I am considering moving over to iTunes, and to grab an Apple TV.  This also would allow me to watch my movies on my iPhone / iPad and through these (via an HDMI adapter) on the upstairs TV.

While I can use iTunes to place parental restrictions on content, I have not yet found out how to bypass this restriction (such as through a password) for 'parental' viewing.  I want content restricted for my kids, but want easy access to higher-rated programs for myself.

Can this be achieved on the iPhone / iPad?  How about the Apple TV?

Comment: Are you sharing one account with your kids? AFAIK restrictions are account based so if you have several accounts this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It's more as far as sharing out to iPad/iPhone/AppleTV that I'm wondering about.  I am hoping to set up a 'server' running iTunes, and just connect to it via the devices.  I shouldn't need to change accounts on the server.

Comment: There is no password to override restrictions in iTunes. Maybe you will get better answers if you rephrase your question to just inquire about ways to control iOS device access to iTunes media based on ratings.

Comment: Slightly reworded.  The password option isn't required, but is just the way Media Center does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be possible to [unlock restricted movie content on request through your Apple TV](http://www.macworld.com/article/1161183/tag_and_restrict.html), but through your iPhone or iPad it appears not to be possible. You can read more on [iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1904), [iOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213), and [Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/parental-controls) parental controls at the included links and in [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5868750/how-do-i-set-up-non+annoying-parental-controls-on-all-my-devices). I hope that this information helps, and let me know if you have any further questions.